# How to add querystring parameters to JavaScript snippets

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I'm trying to answer a question that requires manipulating the querystring parameters of a given page. I wanted to use the snippet editor on Stack Overflow to give an example, but the page that renders the code has a different URL than the page that hosts the editor. Is there a way to pass querystring parameters down from the editor to the page that the editor renders, so my code can use it in the example?

Comment: Just store the parameters in a string, and manipulate that string. There's no reason you should need to use the actual query string to demonstrate anything.

Comment: @meagar, thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing. You can see the result here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272391/64279

Comment: @meager - Do you think you could expand that into an answer and make it a little more generic? I think it is good advice, and I wish more users would actually include a mocked string instead of letting others guess at what the result of a hashed variable stored in some not included place was.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't know that it actually answers the question.

Comment: The actual answer here is "no", you cannot manipulate the location url of a stack snippet. However, the solution to this, and to the broader situation of "how do I represent some obscure string in a post" is simply store it in a separate string.

Comment: It's a hack, but you can use `history.replaceState('', '', '?x=10&y=20')` so that subsequent users of `location.search` will see the value you want.